# Long boot time, stuck on starting a disk which does not appear in fstab

Tags: fedora, boot, fstab

I recently got a problem from my Fedora 31 x64.
While starting up, the OS stuck on

```
A start job is running for /dev/disk/by-uuid/ccd365d0-0305-4b27-b0be-f434bd32b999
```

Then after 1min 30s, it got

```
Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/ccd365d0-0305-4b27-b0be-f434bd32b999
Dependency failed for Resume from hibernation using device /dev/disk/by-uuid/ccd365d0-0305-4b27-b0be-f434bd32b999
```

Most online pages related to this kind of errors were talking about `fstab`. However, here is my `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=3bf4a47c-3b4f-471b-8a33-f0382b0c171f /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
/dev/disk/by-uuid/AE20D54C20D51BE1 /mnt/win7ntfs ntfs-3g nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/C08A4AF68A4AE88C /mnt/ssdntfs ntfs-3g nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/16a9828c-8ace-4293-b3cb-ae79721e8dc8 none swap sw 0 0
```

and here is the `sudo blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="e341ccc7-be41-1fef-fdb8-f63270789736" UUID_SUB="087ca276-07e7-8b36-cdef-f61f375b1658" LABEL="fedora_localhost-live" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="39ea24cf-01"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="e341ccc7-be41-1fef-fdb8-f63270789736" UUID_SUB="2c14618e-a20d-4514-749f-3611fc6726d7" LABEL="fedora_localhost-live" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="360c6a3f-01"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="16a9828c-8ace-4293-b3cb-ae79721e8dc8" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="360c6a3f-02"
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="SSD4Win" UUID="6ABA30A81F399372" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="360c6a3f-03"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="M-cM-^BM-7M-cM-^BM-9M-cM-^CM-^FM-cM-^CM- M-cM-^AM-'M-dM-:M-^HM-gM-4M-^DM-fM-8M-^HM-cM-^AM-?" UUID="AE76D3A576D36D19" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="6af174d2-01"
/dev/sdc2: LABEL="Win7" UUID="AE20D54C20D51BE1" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="atari" PARTUUID="6af174d2-02"
/dev/md127: UUID="3bf4a47c-3b4f-471b-8a33-f0382b0c171f" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
```

As you can see, my laptop does not contain a disk with the UUID `ccd365d0-0305-4b27-b0be-f434bd32b999`, neither does `fstab`.

I have tried `systemctl daemon-reload` and `dracut -f` for several times, but still could not fix the problem.

Comment: What does your grub entry look like for your boot selection?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

I checked `/etc/default/grub` and found this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=UUID=ccd365d0-0305-4b27-b0be-f434bd32b999 rd.md.uuid=e341ccc7:be411fef:fdb8f632:70789736 rhgb quiet"
```

Last month, I replaced `/dev/sdb` which was one of the 2 disks in mdadm RAID 1 array. Hence the UUID of swap partition was also changed. I did not modify the grub configure file.

I corrected the configure file and ran `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`. Everything is going well now.